# Python: Analyze output on application screen

Tags: python

I am trying to automate my login in an application on windows, however the challenge is the application is dynamic at one place while logging in. The following is the code that work fine sometime. Now after the first enter I want python to analyze what is on the screen and then it should either press 1 or skip the step.
Also I would like the people in this community to tell me how do I get more information about the usage of syntax for any module. Is there any website that I could use to increase my knowledge about python?

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time
app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MEDITECH\\Workstation3.x\\T.exe"')
mrw = app.MRW
mrw.Wait('ready')
time.sleep(2)
mrw.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(1)               # This step is not always required
mrw.TypeKeys("1")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("psingh1")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("1234567")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("4")
time.sleep(0.5)
mrw.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: You are looking for some Windows automation tool

Comment: Is it console application? If yes, you can use standard `subprocess` module to deal with `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: A screenshot would be useful.